# No responde ActionListener CommandButton Web App

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, netbeans

Tengo una aplicacion web hecha en `Netbeans 8.1`, `Java 8` y `Maven`

En primer lugar en mi clase `Managed Bean Controller.java` coloque la etiqueta `@ViewScope`. Cuando compile e hice el deploy de la aplicacion me aparecia el error

> Grave:   Exception while loading the app Grave:   Undeployment failed
>   for context /CustomerData1 Grave:   Exception while loading the app :
>   CDI deployment failure:WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope
>   must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class
>   net.ensode.glassfish.jsfajax.Controller] with qualifiers [@Default
>   @Any @Named] org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:
>   WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation
>   capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class
>   net.ensode.glassfish.jsfajax.Controller] with qualifiers [@Default
>   @Any @Named]

Así que lo que hice fue retirar la etiqueta `@ViewScoped` y la aplicacion compilo correctamente y tambien el deploy pero cuando hago click en el `command button` no se ejecuta el codigo del metodo `calculateTotal`, simplemente no hace nunguna accion. ¿ Tiene que ver la etiqueta `@ViewScoped` que elimine del codigo de `controller.java`?

Tambien adjunto el archivo xhtml.

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


//@ViewScoped elimine esta etiqueta y el proyecto compilo y deploy ok.


@Named
public class Controller {

  private String text;
  private int firstOperand;
  private int secondOperand;
  private int total;

  public Controller() {
  }

  public void calculateTotal(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    total = firstOperand + secondOperand;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public int getFirstOperand() {
    return firstOperand;
  }

  public void setFirstOperand(int firstOperand) {
    this.firstOperand = firstOperand;
  }

  public int getSecondOperand() {
    return secondOperand;
  }

  public void setSecondOperand(int secondOperand) {
    this.secondOperand = secondOperand;
  }

  public int getTotal() {
    return total;
  }

  public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
  }
}
```

---

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
     <h:head>
       <title>JSF Ajax Demo</title>
     </h:head>
      <h:body>
        <h2>JSF Ajax Demo</h2>
       <h:form>
      <h:messages/>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:outputText value="Echo input:"/>
        <h:inputText id="textInput" value="#{controller.text}">
          <f:ajax render="textVal" event="keyup"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:outputText value="Echo output:"/>
        <h:outputText id="textVal" value="#{controller.text}"/>
      </h:panelGrid>
      <hr/>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup/>
        <h:panelGroup/>
        <h:outputText value="First Operand:"/>
        <h:inputText id="first" value="#{controller.firstOperand}" size="3"/>
        <h:outputText value="Second Operand:"/>
        <h:inputText id="second" value="#{controller.secondOperand}" size="3"/>
        <h:outputText value="Total:"/>
        <h:outputText id="sum" value="#{controller.total}"/>
        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.calculateTotal}"
                         value="Calculate Sum">
          <f:ajax execute="first second" render="sum"/>
        </h:commandButton>

      </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: probaste a poner action en vez de actionlistener?

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo habilitar el uso de la anotación `@ViewScoped` en tu bean y agregar que tu `Controller` implemente la interfaz `Serializable`. Esto para resolver el problema de WELD-000072, basado en [Java Error:WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9760442/1065197).

Luego, recomiendo realizar los siguientes cambios en tu código:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {
    //...
    public void calculateTotal() {
        total = firstOperand + secondOperand;
    }
    //...
}
```

Y en el código Facelets:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{controller.calculateTotal}"
    value="Calculate Sum">
    <f:ajax execute="first second" render="sum"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Te recomiendo usar `action` antes que `actionListener`. Puedes encontrar mayor explicación de las diferencias entre ellos en el siguiente link: [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267/1065197). BalusC es un gurú en JSF.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda Luiggi, funcionó.

Comment: De nada. Por favor considera [aceptar esta respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227) :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a poner action en vez de actionlistener ya que action sirve para los buttons y los listeners para checkbox,radios...

El action se ejecutaría al pinchar y cada vez que cambie el valor (eso lo haría el actionlistener)

Comment: Nada coloque la propiedad action, pero no funciona. ¿sera por la etiqueta <f:ajax execute="first" render="sum" />? peor no veo nada malo con eso.

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar la respuesta de Luiggi Mendoza, te digo un par de cosas.

Todo backing bean debe tener un **scope**. Un scope define el ámbito de alcance de ese bean en la aplicación. JSF 2.2 ofrece los siguientes scopes:

- ViewScoped: existe tanto mientras se esté en la vista)
- RequestScoped: solo existe mientras dure la petición HTTP)
- FlowScoped: existe mientras dure el flujo definido)
- ConversationScoped: existe mientras no se termine la conversación llamando a `coversation.end()`. Se puede mantener la conversaión entre varias páginas.
- SessionScoped: existe mientras dure la sesión HTTP)
- ApplicationScoped: existe mientras la aplicación esté levantada)

#### ¿Cuándo usar cada scope?

La respuesta la tienes [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

---

Un backing bean debe ser serializado a no ser que sea `RequestScoped`. Esto es porque las vistas se guardan en sesión que vendría a ser `HttpSession` y como sabes todos los atributos de sesión deben ser serializables (porque se persisten en el disco duro u otros medios). Por esta razón la mayoría de tus backing beans deberían implementar `Serializable`.